# Flat read of music files(other than .wav and .mp3) in Python 3

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can read music files (other than .wav or .mp3) in python3. I need a flat reading, without using a decoder.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What do you need to do with the mp3 file?

Comment: I am using wave to read .wav files but when it converts it greatly increases the file size, and that does not work for me, so as I said what I need is a way to read more efficiently music files if there is one?, without using a decoder.
Or using the decoder is good enough?

Comment: Well at some point the audio has to be decoded